# How to set child relationship in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In the Neo4j browser, there is a button  (the button one of the three pictured) that says `expand child relationships` when hovered over. How does one set one node to be the parent or child of another with cyper? [image: Neo4j browser with expand child relationships button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This button essentially expands neighbour nodes of the selected node. So a node is a "child" of another node if they are connected with a relationship (regardless of the direction/type of the relationship).